# Really strange thing with aurelia router params

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I'm trying to set a param id on a reaction object like this:

```
reaction: { message_id: ""};
    async activate(params) {
        alert(params.id);
        this.reaction.message_id = params.id;
    }
```

The alert is correct so It prompts correctly. But then I receive in my console:

```
ERROR [app-router] TypeError: Cannot set property 'message_id' of undefined
```

Edit:

```
import { HttpClient, json } from "aurelia-fetch-client"
import { autoinject } from "aurelia-framework"
import { Router } from 'aurelia-router'

@autoinject
export class message {

    message: {  reactions: Reaction[], id: "" };
    editing: boolean;
    reaction: Reaction;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
        this.editing = false;
    }

    created() {
        this.getMessage();
    }

    async activate(params) {
        alert(params.id);
        this.reaction.message_id = params.id;
    }

    getMessage() {
        this.http.fetch('message/show', {
            body: json(this.router.currentInstruction.params.id)
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.message = data;
            });
    }

    update() {
        this.http.fetch('message/update', {
            body: json(this.message)
        })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status == 200) {
                    swal({
                        title: "Bericht succesvol geupdatet",
                        type: "success",
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        timer: 2000
                    });
                }

                this.editing = false;
            });
    }

    destroy() {
        swal({
            title: 'Weet u het zeker?',
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Ja verwijder dit bericht',
            cancelButtonText: 'Stop!',
            confirmButtonColor: '#002e5b',
        }, (isOk) => {
            if (isOk) {
                this.http.fetch('message/destroy', {
                    body: json(this.message)
                }).then(data => {
                    swal({
                        title: 'Verwijderd',
                        text: 'Het bericht is succesvol verwijderd',
                        type: 'success',
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        timer: 3000
                    });
                });

                this.router.navigate("/dashboard");
            }
        });
    }

    post() {
        this.message.reactions.push(this.reaction);

        this.http.fetch('reaction/store', {
            body: json(this.reaction)
        }).then(response => {
            if (response.status == 200) {
                swal({
                    title: "Reactie succesvol aangemaakt",
                    type: "success",
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    timer: 2000
                });

                this.reaction = {};
            }
        });
    }
}

export class Reaction {
    message_id: number;
    account_id: number;
    reaction: string;
}
```

Comment: `reaction` must be a member of the class. Your code is wrong, so the error makes sense. Try declaring reaction as a member of the class, like `reaction: { message_id: ""};`

Comment: @FabioLuz it's a member of the class. Just simplified it so it's easier to understand.

Comment: hmm can you how the whole class?

Comment: @FabioLuz sure please see my edit.

Comment: reaction is undefined, that's why you get the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only giving a type to `reaction`, not a value. You have to instantiate it before using it. Try this:

```
reaction: Reaction; //this has a type but it is undefined
reaction = new Reaction(); //this has a type and it is instantiated! use this line!
```

This is a simple Typescript problem, nothing related to Aurelia.